# Routing in a single page app(spa) without framework, just javascript

Tags: javascript, routes, single-page-application

I am trying to make a Single Page Application using html, css and javascript. I would like to add some routing to it. I have made server-side rendered websites with nodejs and express. How do I create a routing system for my SPA? Can we use express for client-side routing? If not, are there any alternatives to express for client side routing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a vanilla JS routing for SPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54231533/how-to-create-a-vanilla-js-routing-for-spa). Express doesn't do client-side routing.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use a framework/library for building a SPA, you have two options

1. Use a JS routing library ex: [navigo](https://github.com/krasimir/navigo), didn't try it myself TBH
2. Build it by yourself

To build your own simple SPA Routing, first, you need to:

- Define routing config, each path with the relevant component/element/content to load
- Define your routing root, the element where you will inject the content

Then you have two options:

1. Use # Hash paths (ex: domain.com/#/messages) with window [popstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event) event, so you can handle this event by getting the hash path and decide which content to inject in the root, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54250628/2834925) for more details about his approach
2. Implement a custom routing with normal paths (ex: domain.com/messages), that needs more effort, and to achieve that you need to:

- Implement your custom navigation links, where you need to prevent the default behavior of  navigation, and do the navigation manually using your custom logic
- Use [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API), (ex. pushState) to control the location state and the history stack
- Adjust your server config to always load index.html
- Add your custom logic using the [Location API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) to manage these redirects manually, ie. when a user opens domain.com/messages, it will open index.html, then you need to check manually what the content to load for /messages path and inject it in the root element

Please be aware of the needed time, effort, reliability, maintainability, of each option before starting!